# Convert Row to Column in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am in need of converting the below in multiple files. Text need not be same, but will be in the same format and length

File 1:

```
XXXxx81511
XXX is Present
abcdefg
07/09/2014
YES
1
XXX
XXX-XXXX
```

File 2:

```
XXXxx81511
XXX is Present
abcdefg
07/09/2014
YES
1
XXX
XXX-XXXX
```

TO

```
XXXxx81511,XXX is Present,abcdefg,07/09/2014,YES,1,XXXXXX-XXXX

XXXxx81511,XXX is Present,abcdefg,07/09/2014,YES,1,XXXXXX-XXXX
```

Basically converting row to column and appending to a new file while adding commas to separate them.

I am trying cat filename | tr '\n' ',' but the results do get added in the same line. like this

XXXxx81511,XXX is Present,abcdefg,07/09/2014,YES,1,XXXXXX-XXXX,XXXxx81511,XXX is Present,abcdefg,07/09/2014,YES,1,XXXXXX-XXXX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
paste -sd, file1 file2 .... fileN
#e.g.
paste -sd, *.txt file*
```

prints

```
XXXxx81511,XXX is Present,abcdefg,07/09/2014,YES,1,XXX,XXX-XXXX
XXXxx81511,XXX is Present,abcdefg,07/09/2014,YES,1,XXX,XXX-XXXX
```

and if you need the empty line after each one

```
paste -sd, file* | sed G
```

prints

```
XXXxx81511,XXX is Present,abcdefg,07/09/2014,YES,1,XXX,XXX-XXXX

XXXxx81511,XXX is Present,abcdefg,07/09/2014,YES,1,XXX,XXX-XXXX
```

Short perl variant:

```
perl -pe 'eof||s|$/|,|' files....
```

Comment: Brilliant. Worked just fine. Very very Simple.Wish i could vote up, but i dont have reps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to insert an `echo` after `tr`. Use a script like this:

```
for f in file1 file2; do
    tr '\n' ',' < "$f"; echo
done > files.output
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop:

```
for f in file*; do sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g' < $f; done
```

The `sed` code was taken from [sed: How can I replace a newline (\n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n). `tr '\n' ','` didn't work on my limited test setup.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -ne 'chomp; print $_ . (($. % 8) ? "," : "\n")' f*
```

where:

- `-n` reads the file line by line but doesn't print each line
- `-e` executes the code from the command line
- `8` number of lines in each file
- `f*` glob for files (replace with something that will select all
  your files). If you need a specific order, you will probably need
  something more complicated here.